# How to save long textual data on blockchain?

Tags: string

I need to write blogs and save them on blockchain. What are efficient possibilities to store such data on blockchain?

Thanks for reading the question, already appreciate your time.

Comment: Is your ultimate purpose to have them available to you from a serverless DB (i.e., the blockchain), so that you can read them whenever you want? Or is it to prove to someone that you haven't changed anything in your served DB (e.g., an article on WordPress.org)?

Comment: I want to let users from public create new blog and decentralised it, and no one able to remove the blog except themselves

Comment: I don't think that the blockchain is designated to hold a ton of data (although the idea of using it as a DB with 100% integrity, and no dependency of any single cloud service provider, is quite an appealing one for a brighter future of humanity). But as it stands, storing that much data is simply impractical, cost-wise and time-wise (as in - the amount of time that it would take to complete all the required transactions).

Comment: As far as I understand, the primary goal of the blockchain is storing **evidences (proofs) of integrity**, not the actual data. So you can authenticate the correctness of something, but you cannot retrieve it in plaintext. The general scheme is also known as signature/verification. You store a hash of the data, which is way shorter than the data itself. It can be used for authenticating a given piece of data (by comparing the two hashes), but it cannot be "reverted" back to the original data.

Answer (score 2):

You dont. you should use the blockchain layer to verify the integrity of the data. However, if what you are looking for is distributed storage then you might want to check IPFS & SWARM.

IPFS: https://docs.ipfs.io/
SWARM: https://github.com/ethersphere/swarm